# Square divided by a ray. What is the area of a part?

Tags: geometry

I have a square, for simplicity assume bottom left corner is on origin and width of the square is 1.

A ray divides the square into two parts. I have the coordinates of intersection points. I want to obtain the area that lies right of the vector from `p1` to `p2`:

[image: ray divides square]

Right now I have 16 `if` statements checking every combination of 2 points and calculating the area accordingly. It looks awful. Is there a more clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Call the points **A** and **B** instead of p<sub>1</sub> and p<sub>2</sub>. I'll assume x increases to the right and y increases upward, as per convention.

The point **A** must have a coordinate (x or y) that is 0 or 1. Rotate the square (really just the two points) to make it x=0.

The point **B** might be at x=-1, in which case the area is 1-(A<sub>y</sub>+B<sub>y</sub>)/2.

Or **B** might be at y=0, area = 1+(A<sub>y</sub>B<sub>x</sub>)/2

Or **B** might be at y=1, area = (A<sub>y</sub>-1)B<sub>x</sub>/2

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that p1 and p2 form a right-triangle as depicted in the shaded area:

Area to the right of the vector = (w * w) - (0.5 * p1 * p2)
where w is the width of the square, and 0 <= p1 <= w, and 0 <= p2 <= w.

For example if w = 1, p1 = 0.5, and p2 = 0.75
then Area = (1 * 1) - (0.5 * 0.5 * 0.75) = 0.8125

Comment: They might not form right triangle, they might form trapezoid. And I am already doing the calculations, but it involves 16 `if`s and looks ugly (long, obfuscated, not understandable, prone to bugs etc.) in code, what I am looking for is better solutions if there is.

Comment: Can you supply images, like you did in your original post, that enumerate the types of configurations that p1 and p2 can take?

Comment: Well, let me take a stab at this. To me there seems to be only 3 possible combinations that you need different formulae for: (1) p1 and p2 are on the same side, (2) p1 and p2 are on adjacent sides, and (3) p1 and p2 are on opposite sides. The area calculation for (1) is simply w*w, and for (2) it is stated in my solution. As for (3) you need to break up the shaded area into a rectangle and a right-triangle, add together, and then subtract from the area of the square.

Comment: For all of this to make sense you must have a consistent definition of the origin, and like Beta says p1 and p2 must be treated as points on a rectangular coordinate system having x and y coordinate values. As best I can tell the area of the shaded portion is either zero, the area of a right-triangle, or the combined area of a right-triangle and a rectangle.

Comment: there are 4 sides. p1 can be on one of the sides, p2 can be on one of the sides, therefore there are 4x4=16 possible combinations. For each possible combination, I calculated the formula for the area (zero, triangle or (1-triangle)), wrote `if`s accordingly. I am looking for a better way to write this if possible.

Comment: As my father once said: "there's more than one way to skin a cat." As long as you can prove that your method calculates the expected result for a representative combination of inputs, then you should be pleased with your solution.

Comment: Nimcap, take another look at Beta's solution and ask questions. Ask for further explanation of "rotation". I think its purpose is to locate a corner of the square that is part of the shaded area.